# Open data for Visible cell towers outside the US

Tags: data-request, open-source

I've been trying to find an open data source for cell and radio towers. OSM often includes these, but not in the areas I am looking at outside the US. I've been trying to see what I can get from opencellid.org but as their FAQ says:

> In addition, one of the basic rules of OSM is to map visible things. This is not the case here as MCC/MNC/LAC/CID are not visible in most cases.
> Therefore, only a very small number of cell towers is currently mapped in OSM with MCC/MNC/LAC/CID tags.

What I really need is the location of actual visible large cell towers, and ideally some idea as to their type.

Any ideas?